# Font Awesome Icon is getting cut off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

font awesome icon is getting cut off on the left hand side.

**Snapshot**

[image]

**Below is my code**

```
<div class="media-left">
  <i class="fa fa-search fa-5x text-white"></i>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.media-left{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
 }
    .text-white {
        color: #fff;
    }
    .fa-5x {
        font-size: 5em;
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me https://www.bootply.com/8SbYIL3uPY.  if you have created more table-cells then it may be because of that - if you have a column that is taking up too much space then it may cause other cells to get squashed

Comment: cannot replicate your issue https://jsfiddle.net/tejaspatil6191/605zq8hc/

Answer (score 2):

It might resolve your issue `letter-spacing: 1px;`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have used 5x big font

you can use little search icon as well

```
<div class="media-left">
  <i class="fa fa-search fa-4x text-white"></i>
</div>
```

It might resolve your issue

Comment: Nope! font size is not causing the problem.

Comment: then you have to give padding to media-left

Comment: I know that. I want to know why it is getting cut

Comment: it getting cutoff because font width is big and element width is not that so, so if you give padding it will take 5px width from padding and will look ok

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `display: table-cell;` the icon itself isn't or atleast shouldn't be causing this. It could be another `table-cell` causing this or maybe something else. Since i can't say what is causing it because you haven't provided your other code i can only help you out with maybe another solution.

Since you want the `icon` to be around a single square how about using `display: inline-block` See the snippet below:

```css
.media-left{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: black;
}
.text-white {
    color: #fff;
}
.fa-5x {
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Fonts en Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <!-- JQuery and Bootstrap.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="media-left">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-5x text-white"></i>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is the main restriction of font icons: it should be used only with specific font sizes for avoiding artifacts
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

As mentioned @Dmitro it might help if you are using not `guaranteed` font sizes or using dynamic scaling of your content

```
letter-spacing: 1px;
```

Also additionally next CSS adjustment might help too  :

```
transform: rotate(0.03deg);
```